SAP SAC Customs view not visible after upgrade
We had an update on the SAP system and when searching for custom CDS views in SAC i cannot find any of them anymore. They are all gone but i can open the old stories which use the right analytical views.
But when setting up a new live data connection model i am not able to find any of them starting with 2CZ...
I checked all, i have authorization to all, i cannot see what is blocking me as before the update it was visible.
This is a model which was already available before the update. I can see the model, i can fetch data.
But when i want to setup a new data model based on a live data connection i am not able to find any of the custom views normally beginning with "2CZ...".


Can someone help?

I solved it by changing the release state of Contract C1. (Never heard before)
Make sure the status is Released for 'Use System-Internally (Contract C1)'(see CDS views: HowTo use in BW contexts https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/bwplaolap/3361385699.html).
SAP Help Portal


